# I'm trying to block game "X" from accessing the internet including updating

Tags: firewall

I'm using OS X El Capitan and I'm trying to prevent a game from accessing the internet including blocking it from checking for updates for the launcher or the game itself.

I've gone into Security -> Firewall -> unlocked settings -> Firewall Options -> Found the game in the list and changed it from "Allow incoming connections" to "Block incoming connections" and it still goes out and finds updates and tries to get me to accept them and update the launcher and program.

In my opinion the update has ruined game play so I don't want the update until they either change it back or they fix the game play enough that I want to play it their way. Until then, I want to block it from even *checking* to see if there are updates. I want to be absolutely, totally, offline like there is no network cable and not wireless internet or any other kind of internet.

Since this didn't work, please don't tell me to buy another product. Tell me what I did wrong and how I can fix it with what came with OS X.

Comment: Try Little Snitch (https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) for fine grained access.

Comment: Do you know to which web or ip address it tries to connect?

Comment: Downloading: https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/launcher.pack.lzma

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that the firewall option stops connections from outside to the app but for an update the app initiates the contact to the suppliers server  so the firewall does not help here.

the program [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) does allow you to control the app starting a conversation with another IP address and so can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, Little Snitch is the ultimate solution here allowing you to identify and block all connections. If that's a little heavy-handed for you though the [Radio Silence](http://radiosilenceapp.com/) app offers a simpler way to block specific files from connecting.

Comment: I'm taking a look at Snitch. That might be the answer but I thought that if El Capitan had an easy way to do this that I didn't know about ...

Comment: Well you can block connections in your hosts file without a separate app, but blocking specific apps from connecting to the internet will require a separate app if you want it to be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use [HandsOff!](https://www.oneperiodic.com/products/handsoff/). It works similarly to Little Snitch.

Answer (score 0):

If this is Minecraft, I have a simpler and free solution. If you run the Minecraft launcher from the command line (`java -jar Minecraft.jar`) you can add proxy settings with command-line arguments. If you simply add dummy proxy settings, it will attempt to connect via a proxy that does not exist, blocking network connections.

Running `java -jar Minecraft.jar -help` will list the exact options and their syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit /etc/hosts with "sudo nano /etc/hosts" and put 127.0.0.1 as the ip address for whatever domain it is trying to connect to. Alternatively you can block that IP/domain on your home router, but this would only work when you're at home.