# How to block an app's access to a specific website using the hosts file?

Tags: macos, network, internet, hosts

I want to block an app from connecting to a specific website using the hosts file. How can I do that?

Is something like this possible:

```
127.0.0.1     foo.com:spotify
```

Answer (score 3):

The hosts file is used by the system and can't be used to restrict access for specific apps.

See [I'm trying to block game "X" from accessing the internet including updating](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/214957/37797) for alternative software which is able to block specific apps from accessing specific sites.